# Using a png image format on android devices

Tags: android, air, png, nexus-7

Whenever i am using transparent PNG images, on my android device ( nexus ), i get a border on one side of transparent part. What is the way to sort out this problem ?

Comment: Post the code of how you're using it, and preferably an image of the problem so we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: post the xml code and java code also if you are doing something to ImageView in java code.

Comment: I am using AIR for android. So, there is no code. Just adding image on the stage.

Answer (score 0):

The image you are trying to add may not be transparent.Check it...

In the xml file, use this code to add an `ImageView` and set a resource for it:

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/image"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/sample" />
```

To access the `ImageView` from the java code ,use the following code.

```
 ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
```

You can also set a resource programatically:

```
 imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample);
```